# How to find out which table in TempDB consumed most spaces?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I'm facing the exact  [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944611/failure-sql-query-insufficient-disk-space) and thinking to give it a try on the [solution proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8954996/1460189).

I'm wondering how to query the largest size table in `TempDB` or is there a query whereby it list all tables in tempdb with the respective size

Comment: You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094436/how-to-find-largest-objects-in-a-sql-server-database).

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/tempdb-space-usage-in-sql-server.html , http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2009/11/30/what-s-using-space-in-tempdb/

Answer (score -1):

Tempdb is sufficiently normal that the admin queries work on (temp tables contaiend in) it, despite the fact they don't show up in SSMS. I think that SSMS filters them out.

The temp tables have random names though, so it's kind of hard to determine which query they came from. You can't access them, even with sa (I tried).

So here's half an answer. Anybody who knows the other half can get easy rep.